# Table cell's all same height

Tags: jquery, html, css, tablecell, jquery-steps

I have following code, generated from jQuery steps plugin:

```
<ul>
    <li>
        <a href="#">
            Step 1
        </a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="#">
            Step 2
        </a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="#">
            Step 3
        </a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

The css looks like this:

```
ul li {
    display: table-cell;
    position: relative;
    float: none;
    width: 1%;
}

ul li a {
    display: block;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 12px 18px;
    -webkit-user-drag: none;
    height:100%;
}
```

My problem is, that the output looks weird, when there's too much text for this list:

[image]

How can I fix that? I tried it without the `table-cell` but with `inline-block` formattings, but nothing worked properly. Is there an easy way? A workaround would be counting the letters and then make a `padding-top`, but for me that's nonsense because of the responsiveness of the site.

I tried it with (from [100% height on child of "display: table-cell"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34690646/100-height-on-child-of-display-table-cell)):

```
ul { display:table; }
ul li { display:table-cell; }
ul li a { display:block; height:100%; }
```

But that won't work too.

Comment: Is the CSS also generated?

Comment: The relative height of the child element `ul li a` depends on the fixed height of the parent element, `ul li` which is currently not set. It is therefore dynamically set to the contents of the child.

Comment: @Jay the css is not generated, I could change the css in the plugin-template or overwrite with my own.

Comment: Yeah.. But __why__ are you using position relative for this? If you're creating a navbar, you could easily do so without the use of tables and cells which would fix your problem.